# How to access `\ninerm` (and some others) font in pdfTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize, plain-tex

I can only use `\tenrm\`, `\sevenrm`, and `\fiverm` fonts; there are no `\ninerm` or `\sixrm`. I would appreciate if you share how to make ALL of those font sequences work.

Comment: Plain TeX defines  neither`\ninerm` nor `\sixrm`; it's up to you to define them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\font\ninerm=cmr9
\font\sixrm=cmr6
\ninerm blblb

\sixrm blblb

\bye
```